# Spatie Browsershot cant save image

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, browsershot

[Here is the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzoxt.png)

Spatie\Browsershot\Exceptions\CouldNotTakeBrowsershot
The given path `F:\xampp\htdocs\testcover\public/uploads/` did not contain an extension. Please append an extension

I received this error when trying to save an HTML file as an Image file using Spatie BrowerShot. How can it be fixed. Thanks everyone

Comment: It literally tells you what the issue is???

Comment: Also please include code instead of images. Codes makes it easier for other users, to get help from your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing windows paths with `\` as the separator with linuxs `/` separator, add your path to the `public_path()` call and it should work as intended.

```
$destination = public_path('uploads');
```

Comment: Browsershot::url('https://spatie.be/docs/browsershot/v2/usage/creating-pdfs')
        ->savePdf(public_path('uploads/' . Str::uuid() . '.pdf'));

this didn't work for me

Comment: thinking something like this will help savePdf(public_path('uploads') . '\' . Str::uuid() . '.pdf')

Comment: sorry. this still not working. currently getting this error (i have changed filename as static for testing)

For some reason Chrome did not write a file at `/MY_PROJECT_DIR/public/uploads/test.pdf`. Command ======= [] Output ======

Comment: currently i am using ubuntu 22.04 and node 14 (nvm using for node management)

Comment: erm what is the error? if i remember vaguely there is some problems locally with having the right access rights to actually save the files. Have you tried running it on a proper setup server etc.?

Comment: Yes. on my local machine, js version working properly. I just trying to write code on laravel. my base project is on laravel.

Comment: i am not sure that, i am getting issues because of lack permission of my chromium (chromium does not have access to save files on my local)